# Persian characters are not shown correctly in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a script file of a database. I want add this in mysql.

I created a new database with this command:

```
create DATABASE ppcsystem CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci.
```

Then insert data with script file.

```
Source ppcsystem  > c:\script.sql
```

But when i backup database , persian data not correctly.

`…ÙˆØ²Ø´ ØªÙˆÙ¾Ø®Ø§Ù†Ù‡ Ù†Ø²Ø§Ø¬Ø§`

How to insert persian data in mysql database?

Comment: the database might know it's utf8_persian, but whatever you're using to view that dump text file later won't... Are you **SURE** that the data got stored in mangled form in the database, and this isn't simply a case of incorrect display, and everything in the database is ok?

Comment: I have a script file from a database with perisan text, when i run this script in my database , don't insert correctrl data.